# Accessing a query variable inside a function

Tags: php, function

Okay - I was able to the pass a string assigned to the variable $myfile into the function.  If it could be better, please provide feedback- learning PHP.

```
<?php
$myfile = $row_rs_recordview['headstone'];
echo "$myfile"; // verify the file name
function readGPSinfoEXIF($myfile)
{    
 global $myfile;
 $exif= exif_read_data("headstone/".$myfile, 0, true); //
 if(!$exif || $exif['GPS']['GPSLatitude'] == '') //Determines if the
                          //geolocation data exists in the EXIF data
 {
      return false; //no GPS Data found
      echo "No GPS DATA in EXIF METADATA";
 }
?>
```

Insights appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Pass var(s) as argument(s) to the function?

Answer (score 1):

you can't access the global variables inside function directly.

```
//add global before variable declaration like this
function fun(){  
   global $row_rsUpdate['headstone'];
}
```

Comment: Above code snippet has no syntax error, could you show us the syntax error?

Comment: copy paste the syntax error description here.

Comment: Thanks Aqib.  I've got it working with a little different approach.